# Hide scrollbars in Console without flickering

Tags: c#, scrollbar, console-application

I write in a console window multiple times a second.

I figured out how to remove the scrollbars:

```
Console.BufferWidth = Console.WindowWidth = 35;
Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight;
```

But when I want to write into the last column of a line, it adds a new line. It's logical, but how to avoid this?

I tried to resize the console:

```
Console.BufferWidth++;
Console.BufferHeight++;

// Write to the last column of a line

Console.BufferWidth--;
Console.BufferHeight--;
```

But this flickers because these lines will get executed multiple times a second.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did it with drawing using a native method.

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
    string fileName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileAccess,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileShare,
    IntPtr securityAttributes,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int flags,
    IntPtr template);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Coord
{
    public short X;
    public short Y;

    public Coord(short X, short Y)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }
};

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(
    SafeFileHandle hConsoleOutput,
    string lpCharacter,
    int nLength,
    Coord dwWriteCoord,
    ref int lpumberOfCharsWritten);


public static void Draw(int x, int y, char renderingChar)
{
    // The handle to the output buffer of the console
    SafeFileHandle consoleHandle = CreateFile("CONOUT$", 0x40000000, 2, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

    // Draw with this native method because this method does NOT move the cursor.
    int n = 0;
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(consoleHandle, renderingChar.ToString(), 1, new Coord((short)x, (short)y), ref n);
}
```

[WriteConsoleOutputCharacter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687410%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not move the cursor. So even while drawing in the last column of the last row, the cursor does not jump into the next line (outside of window size) and break the view.

Comment: How call method `Draw(int x, int y, char renderingChar)` ?

Answer (score 13):

Try with Console.SetBufferSize(width, height); I think it will help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that the cursor goes to the next line directly. What it really does is, it goes one character to the right and because the buffer ends it goes to the next line.

So I tried to do something like Console.WriteLine("C\r"); To set the cursor back but it still flickered

Than I thought about using some sneaky trick and using an Arabic Right to Left Marker but didn't worked.

So the best way i could figured out was to **move the character** to the bottom right **with** the **Console.MoveBufferArea** method because **this doesn't set the cursor to the next right position and avoids the new line**.

Answer (score 1):

i have a working code if u want completely hide vertical scrollbar of console app.

here we go ..

this works with any resolution.

Tested by me.

```
class Program
    {
        private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
        public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
        public const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;
        public const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;
        public const int SC_SIZE = 0xF000;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition,intwFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var largestWindowX = Console.WindowWidth;
            var largestWindowY = Console.WindowHeight;
            
            Console.BufferWidth = Console.WindowWidth = largestWindowX;
            Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight = largestWindowY;

            IntPtr handle = GetConsoleWindow();
            IntPtr sysMenu = GetSystemMenu(handle, false);

            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
                DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_MINIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
                DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
                DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_SIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There should be a space to separate 'int' and 'wFlags' on the first public static extern import but bar this, this solution did exactly as described. Thanks for the help!