# C# Console Buffer and Console Resize Event

Tags: c#, winapi, console, resize, buffer

I'm working on a console project in C# and can't seem to find what I'm looking for:

How can I grab the resize event of a console in C# before it actually occurs or while it's occurring, so that I have a chance to increase the buffer size along with the window size?

edit: adjusted question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide scrollbars in Console without flickering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568127/hide-scrollbars-in-console-without-flickering)

Comment: Chicken-and-egg problem, resizing is only possible when the buffer is larger than the window.  The user can make the window smaller, not bigger.  But that in turn ruins the effect you are looking for, text is no longer at the top and bottom of the window.  Technically you can get [resize notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it requires pretty drastic changes in your code.  You'll be half-way to implementing a GUI.  Which is the better solution in general.